# Dynamic Upper & Lower Bounds in Power BI

Tags: filter, dynamic, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I created line chart in power BI like this:
[image]

I have Upper line, Lower line and result line.
I want to add dynamic filter that the user can write value between 0 to 1 and then the upper and lower will move. I mean, I want the upper and lower limits to move according to the value that the user entered by multiplying by a percentage. for example, if the upper limit is 100 and the lower limit is -50 and the user entered 0.5 then the upper limit will be 50 and the lower limit will be -25.

I created a Tresh-hold with values between 0to 1 like this:

```
Tresh-hold = GENRATESERIES(0,1,0.01)
```

how can I create that filter? I don't know how to connect the Tresh-hold table to the Upper and Lower lines?

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how to do the upper and you can follow the same pattern for the lower.

Threshold Table:

[image]

My data table:

[image]

There are no relationships between the two.

Create a single measure as follows:

```
Upper = MAX(Threshold[Value])*100
```

Add a slicer to the report and set to less than or equal to in the slicer settings. Connect to your threshold value so it looks like this.

[image]

On your line chart, go to the analytics pane and add a y-axis constant line.

[image]

For the value of the constant, select fx and then your measure.

The slicer is now connected to your line chart upper boundary. You can repeat for lower.

Comment: What version of POWER BI are you using? I have 2021 and  Y-Axis Line 1 is not Dynamic, I can't choose FX and insert my  measure, just a number.

Comment: Why are you using a 2 year old version and not the most recent release?

Comment: this is the version where I work. thanks anyway =), I will try to figure it out

Comment: You should mention in your future posts that you're working with a very old version. You will be missing a lot of options if you don't upgrade.